# I want to get data from my own server instead of nasa servers in java worldwind

Tags: java, worldwind

In the worldwind java project, I wrote my own localhost server link instead of nasa server links in the layer.xml files. but the project still continues to pull data from nasa. What exactly should I do to pull the data from my own site?

the code of the xml file I edited:

```
<Layer version="1" layerType="TiledImageLayer">
    <DisplayName>Blue Marble (WMS) 2004</DisplayName>
    <Service serviceName="OGC:WMS" version="1.3">
        <GetCapabilitiesURL>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/explorer/index.html</GetCapabilitiesURL>
        <GetMapURL>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/explorer/index.html</GetMapURL>
        <LayerNames>bmng200405</LayerNames>
    </Service>
    <RetrievePropertiesFromService>true</RetrievePropertiesFromService>
    <!-- day month year hours:minutes:seconds timezone -->
    <LastUpdate>26 03 2009 00:00:00 GMT</LastUpdate>
    <DataCacheName>Earth/BMNGWMS/BMNG(Shaded + Bathymetry) Tiled - Version 1.1 - 5.2004</DataCacheName>
    <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
    <AvailableImageFormats>
        <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
        <ImageFormat>image/dds</ImageFormat>
    </AvailableImageFormats>
    <FormatSuffix>.dds</FormatSuffix>
    <NumLevels count="5" numEmpty="0"/>
    <TileOrigin>
        <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
    </TileOrigin>
    <LevelZeroTileDelta>
        <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="36" longitude="36"/>
    </LevelZeroTileDelta>
    <TileSize>
        <Dimension width="512" height="512"/>
    </TileSize>
    <Sector>
        <SouthWest>
            <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="-90" longitude="-180"/>
        </SouthWest>
        <NorthEast>
            <LatLon units="degrees" latitude="90" longitude="180"/>
        </NorthEast>
    </Sector>
    <ForceLevelZeroLoads>true</ForceLevelZeroLoads>
    <RetainLevelZeroTiles>true</RetainLevelZeroTiles>
    <UseTransparentTextures>false</UseTransparentTextures>
    <RetrievalTimeouts>
        <ReadTimeout>
            <Time units="milliseconds" value="30000"/>
        </ReadTimeout>
    </RetrievalTimeouts>
    <!-- The following lines are included just to show how to set the values to other than their defaults -->
    <MaxAbsentTileAttempts>2</MaxAbsentTileAttempts>
    <MinAbsentTileCheckInterval>1000</MinAbsentTileCheckInterval>
</Layer>
```

I still see the timeout error I get when I run the project, trying to pull data from NASA's site.

```
Sep 09, 2021 2:44:50 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheRetrievalPostProcessor run
SEVERE: Retrieval failed for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/elev?EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0
Sep 09, 2021 2:44:50 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.util.SessionCacheUtils retrieveSessionData
SEVERE: Exception while retrieving resources for https://worldwind26.arc.nasa.gov/elev?EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: We will not able to identify the actual cause till we cant access code

Comment: I edited the topic

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are loading the config file you want (there might be one *inside the worldwind.jar* so be explicit):

```
System.setProperty("gov.nasa.worldwind.config.file","path/to/worldwind.xml");
```

Then clear the WorldWind download cache, just in case.

[Configuration Documentation Here](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/Configuration.html)